# Nohup not working with "." or ksh

Tags: ksh, nohup

I have a very unique issue. I have a *.b file, which I usually execute by putting a "." or the command ksh in front the name of the file. It usually works fine, but I tried to do the same using nohup and it won't work.

I put the following line:

```
nohup . file.b param1 param2 &
```

or

```
nohup ksh file.b param1 param2 &
```

Comment: `nohup` requires an external command; `.` is a shell built-in.

Comment: So, what do you suggest I should do?

Comment: Define "won't work".  Does file.b produce output that you need?  More info needed here.

Comment: No, it does not produce anything. I think it doesn't recognize "." as a valid command to execute the .b . The same happens for ksh. I can't reproduce the error right now because the server I have to connect to is having connectivity issues at the moment. As soon as I can, I will copy here the error that pops up. Thank you guys

Comment: `chmod +x file.b && nohup file.b param1 param2 &`

Comment: Doing this, it says (translating from spanish): input ignored and output added to «nohup.out». Next line: nohup: failed to execute the order  «file.b»: file or directory does not exist. This last line is the same that pops when I just write from nohup, without the first part. I am 100% sure the file is in the directory I am in, so I don't understand the error. Thank you for your help

Comment: `nohup . file.b` won't work.  `nohup ksh file.b ...` might, but it depends really on what happens inside file.b